# Autoplay a animated graphic element that is a node of a tikzpicture inside an item

Tags: beamer, itemize, animate

How can I autoplay the animated graphic when the item is visible? This my code (the animated graphic is into the second item. Now the graphics start when I click on it

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<1-> item1
        \item<2-> item with the animated graphic
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node<2>[inner sep=0pt] (video1) at (-1.5,.1) {\animategraphics[loop,width=.4\textwidth,autoplay]{8}{graphics/frames/breaststroke/breaststroke-}{0}{29}}; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \item<3-> item3 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this works for me, no additional click needed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<1-> item1
        \item<2-> item with the animated graphic
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node<2>[inner sep=0pt] (video1) at (-1.5,.1) {\animategraphics[loop,width=.4\textwidth,autoplay]{8}{example-image-a4-numbered}{}{}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \item<3-> item3 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(Always provide a compilable example, as indicated in the comment to your question.)

Comment: Thank you. What was the pdf viewer that you used?

Comment: Acrobat Reader.